# Vb.net/C# make classes store value types

Tags: c#, vb.net, class, value-type

I need to declare a class whose properties are stored as value types. I also need to make my class inheritable, so I can't make it a structure.

```
Class MyClass
...
End Class

Class InheritingClass
Inherits MyClass
...
End Class
```

Is there any other way to do this without converting it to a structure and using interfaces? (example below)

```
Structure MyStructure
Implements MyInterface
...
End Structure

Structure InheritingStructure
Implements MyInterface
...
End Structure

Interface MyInterface
...
End Interface
```

PS: You can post the answer in C# if you don't know vb

Comment: can you show at least one of these properties

Comment: What do you mean? Classes can contain value type fields, no problem. Properties don't "store" values at all; they are just getters and setters. As with any other field, the class fields that back the properties can be value types. What is it that you are trying to do that you think you can't do? Please be _specific_. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need your type to be a value-type, there is no other way than making it a `struct`.

Maybe, if you give more context, leading to another question, we might find a better solution to your actual problem.